# Tkinter Image Updating Image + lambda Error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

As of late I have been basically self-teaching myself Tkinter. I've been working on this project for about a week now and I feel like it's coming along rather nicely. Today while I was working on it I got this code, which when ran successfully sets up the GUI. However, when I try to change the image via the `Combobox`, it fails and gives me the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

After a quick search I found that using `lambda x:` would fix this error. After making this change, the GUI initiates as normal, however the images will still not change, in fact, the second panel glitches out and removes the image if an item is selected from the first `Combobox`. Complete removal of 'lambda' causes the panels to not be initiated at all. Basically, I would like to know what is causing these glitches and how to get my images to update.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        parent.title('Vainglory DMG Calculator | BETA')
        self.dyn_panel = []
        self.dyn_combobox = []
        self.dyn_image_path = ['', '']
        self.dyn_img = ['', '']
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.hero_list = ('Adagio', 'Alpha', 'Ardan', 'Baptiste', 'Baron', 'Blackfeather', \
                          'Catherine', 'Celeste', 'Churnwalker', 'Flicker', 'Fortress', \
                          'Glaive', 'Grace', 'Grumpjaw', 'Gwen', 'Idris', 'Joule', \
                          'Kestrel', 'Koshka', 'Krul', 'Lance', 'Lorelai', 'Lyra', 'Ozo', \
                          'Petal', 'Phinn', 'Reim', 'Reza', 'Ringo', 'Rona', 'Samuel', \
                          'SAW', 'Skaarf', 'Skye', 'Taka', 'Varya', 'Vox')
        for i in range(2):
            self.create_hero_combo_box(parent, i)
            self.set_image(i)            
            self.create_hero_panel(parent, self.dyn_img[i], i)

    def create_hero_panel(self, window, img, index):
        self.dyn_panel.append(Label(window, image=img))
        self.dyn_panel[index].grid(row=0, column=index*2)

    def create_hero_combo_box(self, window, index):
        self.dyn_combobox.append(Combobox(window, values=(*self.hero_list,)))
        self.dyn_combobox[index].grid(row=1, column=index*2)
        self.dyn_combobox[index].set(self.hero_list[0])

    def set_image(self, index):
        self.dyn_image_path[index] = (self.cwd + '/img/heroes/' + self.dyn_combobox[index].get().lower() + '.png')
        self.dyn_img[index] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.dyn_image_path[index]))

    def update(self, index):
        self.dyn_panel[index].configure(image=self.set_image(index))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    for i in range(2):
        app.dyn_combobox[i].bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda x: app.update(i))
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: better use `lambda x=i : app.update(x)` because this way it will use correct value from `i` instead of reference to `i` which will keep different value.

Comment: After doing so I get a new error: `File "C:\Users\brigh\Downloads\vg_calc\test.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    app.dyn_combobox[i].bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda x=i: app.update_image(x))
  File "C:\Users\brigh\Downloads\vg_calc\test.py", line 42, in update_image
    self.set_image(index)
  File "C:\Users\brigh\Downloads\vg_calc\test.py", line 38, in set_image
    self.dyn_image_path[index] = (self.cwd + '/img/heroes/' + self.dyn_combobox[index].get().lower() + '.png')
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Event`

Comment: my mistake, `bind()` executes function with `event` as argument - you need `lambda event, x=i : app.update(x)` to get this `event` and skip it.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm, thank you very much

Comment: btw: if you will run it from different folder - ie as link/shortcut on desktop - then `os.getcwd()` gives you path to desktop, not to folder with your program, and it doesn't find your files. You have to use `self.cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))`

Answer (score -1):

Every widget has method `update()` but you create `update()` in `App(Frame)` so you replace it - and it can makes problem. Use different name than `update()`

Comment: ah, I do see how that can be an issue, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: While you are technically correct, it has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley what do you mean ? Do you mean original `update` doesn't get arguments but new one expects `index` ?

Comment: @furas: I mean that the problem remains whether the method is named `update` or anything else. While calling it `update` can lead to misunderstandings, it doesn't affect how the code works since the code is never trying to call the original built-in `update` command.

Comment: @BryanOakley now I see. I tested it only with new name and it worked correctly so I assumed it resolved problem. I can't reproduce problem on Linux - it always works.